# Kernel Density Estimate on point data in degrees (scikit-learn)

Tags: heat-map, kernel-density, scikit-learn

I am estimating point density, where I am having point coordinates in degrees, I need a raster(over the extent of these points) which provides a density estimation on each cell.

I have tried on R but I have not got any success as the extent of my point data is very large. I am trying scikit-learn package in python, but stucked with the implementation.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.neighbors import KernelDensity
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import gdal
import os
import ogr
import osr
from sklearn.cluster import DBSCAN

def density_Viz(str_InputSHP):
    driver = ogr.GetDriverByName('ESRI Shapefile')
    ds = driver.Open(str_InputSHP)
    layer = ds.GetLayer(0)
    lst_train = []
    lst_coord = []
    for feat in layer:
        geom = feat.GetGeometryRef()
        X = geom.GetX()
        Y = geom.GetY()
        xy = (X, Y)
        lst_coord.append(xy)
        lst_train.append([X, Y])

    # val=getKernelDensityEstimation(lst_coord)
    lst_train = np.array(lst_train)
    lat_lon_val = lst_train.copy()
    lst_train *= np.pi / 180.
    # create grid
    (dblXmin, dblXmax, dblYmin, dblYmax) = layer.GetExtent()
    pixelWidth = 0.00082
    Nx = int((dblXmax - dblXmin)/pixelWidth)
    Ny = int((dblYmax - dblYmin)/pixelWidth)
    xmin = dblXmin + 0.0008
    xmax = xmin + (Nx * pixelWidth)
    ymin = dblYmin + pixelWidth
    ymax = ymin + (Ny * pixelWidth)
    # x coordinates of the grid cells
    xgrid = np.arange(xmin, xmax, pixelWidth)
    # y coordinates of the grid cells
    ygrid = np.arange(ymin, ymax, pixelWidth)

    X, Y = np.meshgrid(xgrid, ygrid)
    xy = np.vstack([X.ravel(), Y.ravel()]).T
    xy *= np.pi / 180.

    kde = KernelDensity(bandwidth=(0.0032*np.pi/180), metric='haversine',
                        kernel='epanechnikov', algorithm='ball_tree', breadth_first=False).fit(lst_train)

    val = kde.score_samples(lst_train)
    val1 = kde.score_samples(xy)

    print(np.amax(val))  # getting 16, expected value is nearly 70
    print(np.amin(val))  # getting 13
    print(np.amax(val1))  # getting 16
    print(np.amin(val1))  # getting -Inf
    print("Done")
```